# Is there a way to compare 2 packed qwords in one instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, avx

I'm experimenting with `SSE`/`AVX` extensions and now looking at `pcmpxstrx` family of instructions. As specified in the Intel instruction reference it provides an ability to compare 2 string stored in the `xmm` registers. So for example

```
mov rax, 0x22223333
movq xmm0, rax

mov rax, 0x22221111
movq xmm1, rax

pcmpistri xmm0, xmm1, 0001b
```

results in setting `rcx` to the value 1. That works fine on words, but I'm looking for a way to perform such comparison of `packed qwords` in `ymm` registers. As far as I can see even `AVX` does not promote `pcmpistri` to 256 bits

```
VPCMPISTRI xmm1, xmm2/m128, imm8        AVX
```

So the only way is to use `VPCMPEQQ` with `BSF` (2 instructions)?

Comment: Compare/kmov/bsf is faster than `pcmpistri`

Comment: @harold: or without AVX512 for compare into mask + `kmov`, you'd use `vpcmpeqq ymm0, ymm1, ymm2` / `vpmovmskpd eax, ymm0` / `bsf`.  And yes, each of those are single-uop so the combination not worse than multi-uop `pcmpistri` (Ryzen: 2 uops, 11c latency.  Or Skylake: 3 uops for port 0, 10c latency)

Comment: @PeterCordes Can you give a reference where you took these uops/latency info from? Intel instruction reference does not seem to provide something like this. Or you measured it by yourself?

Comment: @St.Antario: https://uops.info/, or (including AMD CPUs as well) https://agner.org/optimize/.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for performance links.